# GCC `-fsanitize=bounds` strange behaviour with `std::array`

Tags: c++, arrays, g++

I'm trying find out of bounds problems in my code using `-fsanitize=bounds` option, but I faced with strange behaviour:

For instance in the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>

int main (int, char **)
{
    std::array <char, 1> a;
    const char b = a [X]; // X <--- put index here!

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

compiled with options: `$ g++ -std=c++11 -fsanitize=bounds -O0 main.cpp -o main`.

If I try access to element with index more than 1, errors are reported:
`/usr/include/c++/5/array:53:36: runtime error: index 2 out of bounds for type 'char [1]'` .

But if I try access to element with index 1, everything OK and no errors are reported.

Is it expected behaviour and may be I've missed something?

The example is tested on:

- `$ g++ --version g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609`;
- `$ g++ --version g++ (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005`.

**UPDATE**
I tried `-fsanitize=bounds-strict` in GCC 6 and resulted the same.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, my question about using `ubsan` tool but not about language.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to use std::array with N == 1 and refer to indices out of bounds?

Comment: @foxfireee, if it's make you happy you can use N==1024*1024 and try access to element 1024*1024 somewhere inside loop.

Comment: I'm making this a comment: a possible workaround is to use `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to diagnose out of bounds accesses. MSVC also does this by default in debug mode.

Comment: @Gluttton If you want to check bounds, use function "at" instead of "operator []".

Answer (score 2):

I can't immediately find documentation for this (or, really, strong documentation of any kind), but it strikes me as likely that this is an implementation detail for the feature. It is legal to obtain one-past-the-end pointers, so an implementation could not trap on this. It seems the implementation works by looking at the pointer, rather than waiting for such a pointer to be dereferenced (which makes some sense if you think about how you would create `-fsanitize=bounds`).

In short, this may simply be a limitation of the tool.

In GCC 6, you might try `-fsanitize=bounds-strict` which increases the strength of the tool (including adding support for detecting OOB access to flexible member-like arrays).

I can't tell whether this is a library or compiler issue, but either way it's worth noting that the same problem is currently an open bug against clang ([#21485](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21485)), and the supposition in comments there matches my ramblings above.

[A third-party article on *ubsan*](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/10/16/gcc-undefined-behavior-sanitizer-ubsan/) also implies that this is, ultimately, expected behaviour.

Comment: `it's worth noting that the same problem is currently an open bug against clang` - my issue a little bit difference and reproduced only with `std::array` (with C-like array it works well).

Answer (score 1):

As @Ripi2  [mentioned](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/iterators.html), the first element past the end of the array often considered as end iterator.

In this case, [-fsanitize=address](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#:%7E:text=indirect%20call%20profiling.-,-fsanitize%3Daddress,-Enable%20AddressSanitizer%2C%20a) can detect out-of-bound bugs, when you access illeagal position of array, compiler can give more info.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fsanitize=address -O0 main.cpp -o main
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html

> -fsanitize=bounds
>       This option enables instrumentation of array bounds. Various out of bounds accesses are detected. Flexible array members, flexible
>   array member-like arrays, and initializers of variables with static
>   storage are not instrumented.

Using X>1 makes this check (array out of bounds) to trigger, as expected because of 'a' char declaration, with size = 1.

#### EDIT

Being that said, as @Lightness Races in Orbit says, this is not an answer. But offers some info for readers.

The fact that the case X==1 is one-past-end makes me think of iterators, where one-past-end is allowed. IOW, it seems that GCC sanitizer gets an iterator for testing instead of a reference a[X].

@Gluttton confirms that using C-like array instead of std::array the case a[1] is showed as an error, as expected.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is why `X == 1` isn't also considered a violation (as one might expect).

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/iterators.html explains why one-past-the-end doesn't trigger error.

Comment: I think a{X] is considered as an iterator, at least for this kind of check.