# Is it well-defined that C++ will do the array boundary check in literal class constructor at compiling time?

Tags: c++

I found running the following code (clang 5.0/gcc7.1 with std=c++17) at compiling time, it will report an out of bounds error

```
int dummy[1];

struct CTest {
  constexpr CTest()  {
        dummy[100] = 1;
  }
};

constexpr CTest t;  // error: array subscript value ‘100’ is outside the bounds of array ‘dummy’ of type ‘int [1]’
```

But running a normal function in compiling time, it will not report the error.

```
constexpr int foo(int i)
{
    dummy[1000] = i;
    return i;
}
int a[foo(1)];    //force foo run at compile time, no compile error
```

I am wondering whether this behavior is well-defined that in in literal class constructor it will check the boundary.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45487308/1896169

Comment: GCC supports VLAs, so you should not expect an error when sizing an array at run-time - use `-pedantic` to get a warning.

Comment: @NeilButterworth are you sure you got the question correctly?

Comment: Out of bounds accesses and other UB *in constant expressions and constexpr functions* are diagnosable and required to be reported. UB elsewhere may or may not go unnoticed. [see e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421170/constexpr-undefined-behaviour)

Comment: @Justin That is different question, because here I define dummy[1], not dummy[0]

Comment: @camino Yes. That's why that question is only "Related"